# File diff in MSBuild?

Tags: file, msbuild, diff, task

How do I diff two files in MSBuild? I cannot find any specific task to do it.

If possible, is it also possible to exclude certain rows, or patterns in the files eg.
2009-12-09T10:03:07.6888125+02:00

Comment: [How To: Implementing Custom Tasks - Part I](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to write your own `MSBuild` task which wraps some difftool commandline app. For commandline apps, you can inherit from the `ToolTask` class, which provides quite a bit of command line plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Target Name="CheckFileSyncStatus" BeforeTargets="Build" Inputs="@(FilesToSync -> '..\..\..\folder1\folder2\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" Outputs="@(FilesToSync)">
<Exec Command="FC &quot;%(FilesToSync.Filename)%(FilesToSync.Extension)&quot; &quot;..\..\..\folder1\folder2\%(FilesToSync.Filename)%(FilesToSync.Extension)&quot;">
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="FCExitCode" />
</Exec>
<Error Text="[HP.OneDriver.Win10S.DriverProperties]:Files out of sync from source: %(FilesToSync.Filename)%(FilesToSync.Extension)" Condition="FCExitCode == 1" />
```